# How to get inner color tag matches using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, tags, pattern-matching, richtext

I have this one problem, what pattern I should use to find all rich text color tags within other color tags?

So for example I have this input:

```
<color=yellow>Hello <color=cyan>World!</color></color>
```

And remove, by replacing with empty string matched tags and have this as an input after:

```
<color=yellow>Hello World!</color>
```

It could be even more tags within, for example:

```
<color=yellow>Hello my <color=cyan>name</color> is <color=gray>Kite <color=white>Watson!</color></color></color>
```

And have this after:

```
<color=yellow>Hello my name is Kite Watson!</color>
```

The reason I need this is because I use Regex to apply code highlighter to text in text box and some keywords are colorized within comments, like in below example

[image]

So I want to check and remove if there are any color tags within color tags, like in this comment example.

I'm pretty new to Regex, so currently a bit lost and not sure what to do. Can someone give me some advice on how can I accomplish this? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a bit different approach.

```
    Regex tags = new Regex(@"<color=#.*?>|<\/color>");
    MatchCollection matches = tags.Matches(c);

    bool hasStarted = false;
    int innerTags = 0;

    const string tempStart = "Â¬Â¬Â¬Â¬Â¬Â¬Â¬Â";
    const string tempEnd = "Â~Â~Â~Â~";
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        if (match.Value.Contains("<color=#"))
        {
            if (hasStarted)
            {
                var cBuilder = new StringBuilder(c);
                cBuilder.Remove(match.Index, match.Length);
                cBuilder.Insert(match.Index, tempStart);

                c = cBuilder.ToString();

                innerTags++;
            }
            else
            {
                hasStarted = true;
            }
        }
        else if (match.Value.Equals("</color>"))
        {
            if (innerTags > 0)
            {
                var cBuilder = new StringBuilder(c);
                cBuilder.Remove(match.Index, match.Length);
                cBuilder.Insert(match.Index, tempEnd);

                c = cBuilder.ToString();

                innerTags--;
            }
            else if (innerTags <= 0)
            {
                hasStarted = false;
            }
        }
    }
    c = c.Replace(tempStart, string.Empty);
    c = c.Replace(tempEnd, string.Empty);
```

Not sure if it's the best way, but it works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all tags except first and last and you get what you desire using following regex,

```
(?<!^)<[^>]*>(?!$)
```

This basically matches all tags except first and last using negative look around. Let me know if this works for your scenario else I can strengthen the regex further.

[Check this Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sEN48S/1)

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the reply! :) This works well, but is there a way to match specifically color tags, cause some inputs may contain these symbols < > and I don't want to remove them, only the <color and </color>. I tried to modify your provided pattern, but I can't seem to match the close tag: (?<!^)<color[^>]*>(?!$)

Comment: @UnknownUser: Sure, we can just match color tags only. Let me edit my solution

Comment: I tested a bit the example pattern you provided and I ran into some issues. This pattern removed almost all my color tags from the text. https://regex101.com/r/AnAd98/1 In the example code, it should only remove the color tag from the is keyword that is located within the above update method comment. Does this require different kind of pattern?

Comment: @UnknownUser: Hey buddy, I didn't knew how your data exactly was. Now that you have posted your actual data, I have changed the approach of my regex. Check this https://regex101.com/r/sEN48S/2/ for your data and tell me if it works fine. If it works well then I will update my post else will change my regex to further cover your cases.

Comment: Thank you! :) Unfortunately this pattern still removes all the other tags :/, in the example here https://regex101.com/r/AnAd98/3, the only tag that should be removed is the one that surrounds is keyword, which is the inner tag of the comment. Other tags that are not surrounded by <color=>..</color>, should not be matched. Is there a way to check maybe if certain words (which are <color=..> and </color> are surrounded by <color=..></color>?

Comment: @UnknownUser: You forgot to replace using `\1\2` as in my regex example. I've added that in your regex101 demo. Check this where it only removes color tags in the middle ones and first one and last one is ignored. https://regex101.com/r/AnAd98/4 I am capturing the ones to be retained in group1 and group2 and rest are getting removed.

Comment: @UnknownUser: And just in case if you want to get rid of inner color tags only, use this https://regex101.com/r/AnAd98/5

Comment: @tgralex: My initial solution won't work as his actual input text is a little different than originally posted example. My this regex101 demo https://regex101.com/r/AnAd98/5 should be able to handle all cases as mentioned by OP.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far! :) I really appreciate it! The latest example you showed works well, the only issue with the pattern is that it treats for example this <color=#3D8CBF>using</color> <color=#00FFFF>UnityEngine</color>; as one tag, it would remove the middle </color> and <color=#00FFFF> even though these are two separate tags. https://regex101.com/r/AnAd98/7 The inner tag would be if after <color=> there is another <color=>, but if after <color=> there is </color> it means the tag has no inner tags. Is there a way to check that?